# How to download a file to local from Aspose.Cloud?

Tags: c#, .net, aspose

I am trying to convert doc to pdf using Aspose.Words-Cloud but the conversion API uploads the converted file to cloud and I can't find a clear way to download it to local via code.

This is the code provided by Aspose.Cloud,

```
private static void downloadToLocal(Configuration config, string path) 
{ 
  StorageApi storageApi = new StorageApi(config);
  GetDownloadRequest request = new GetDownloadRequest(); 
  request.Path = path; 
  request.Storage = null; 
  request.VersionId = null; 
  var response = storageApi.GetDownload(request); 
}
```

but it is not clear which library *StorageApi* and *GetDownloadRequest* are  a part of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are using some old SDK version of Aspose.Words Cloud. Please note since [19.4](https://blog.aspose.cloud/2019/06/03/improved-aspose-words-cloud-v4-is-here/) release, now Aspose.Words Cloud API has its own storage methods for storage operations. Please use the latest version of Aspose.Words Cloud SDK for .NET from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Aspose.Words-Cloud/) to download a file to a local drive from cloud storage as follows.

P.S: I am a developer evangelist at aspose.cloud.

```
public static async Task DownloadStorageFile_Word()
{

    Aspose.Words.Cloud.Sdk.Configuration config = new Aspose.Words.Cloud.Sdk.Configuration();
    config.ClientId = ClientId;
    config.ClientSecret = ClientSecret;

    Aspose.Words.Cloud.Sdk.WordsApi wordsApi = new Aspose.Words.Cloud.Sdk.WordsApi(config);
    // Download a File from Cloud Storage
    var downloadRequest = new Aspose.Words.Cloud.Sdk.Model.Requests.DownloadFileRequest("Output.pdf",null,null);
    var actual = await wordsApi.DownloadFile(downloadRequest);
    var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(@"C:\Temp\Output.pdf");
    actual.CopyTo(fileStream);
    fileStream.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. Also is there a source where I can find the updated reference for latest version of packages because I still have a number of questions related to it.

Comment: @TusharAnand, you may refer to online WEB API Explorer(https://apireference.aspose.cloud/words/) or documentation(https://docs.aspose.cloud/words/) for the requirements. If you have any concerns or suggestions ,then you can also post your query in our public forums(https://forum.aspose.cloud/c/words/17).